# Interactive zoom with y axis autoscale

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to alter the behavior of the interactive zoom-to-rectangle so that data are autoscaled on the y axis based on the new visible x axis range. Indeed I am exploring a lot of telemetry data with large dynamic and I need to zoom back and forth a lot. So it would be good to have autoscaling of the y axis. After much googling and searching the forum I've not found anything that helped to achieve that. Or may be I searched wrong.
Could anyone give me some guidance ?

Comment: What does "autoscaled based on the new axis" mean? Could you explain that using an actual example code?

Comment: Let's use a simple example where I plot y=f(x). Once plotted I use the magnifier button to create a zoom rectangle which spans from x1 to x2 range, let's ignore the y span of this rectangle. I would like the zoom to display the data between x1 and x2 with y spanning from min to max of y=f(x) in the x1 to x2 range.

Comment: I see. Two questions though: Does it have to be the rectangle zoom tool that does that? And would you ever not want to restrict the shown range to the min-max of f(x)?

Comment: First, thanks for your help. The rectangle zoom is convenient as I would be zooming a lot for data exploration. But I'm open to alternatives. I'm good with always restricting the zoom to min-max of f(x) as I always need to see the full range of the signal. I'm working on a code prototype that I will post shortly. But it is using bits and pieces that I hardly understand and it's not working. But that will probably help to explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to connect to the `xlim_changed` signal and calculate, based on the current x limits, the new limits for the y axis such that all data is included.

The following does this and it's a bit more complicated than initially thought, because just setting the y limits will not work, because they would be overwritten by the (simultaneous) `ylim_changed` event that the zooming triggers. So instead, there is a timer set to 10 milliseconds, that artificially sets the limits, after that event has been processed.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class AutoScaleY():
    def  __init__(self, line, margin=0.05):
        self.margin = margin
        self.line = line
        self.ax = line.axes
        self.ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self.rescale_y)

    def rescale_y(self,evt=None):
        xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
        x, y = line.get_data()
        cond = (x >= xmin) & (x <= xmax)
        yrest = y[cond]
        margin = (yrest.max()-yrest.min())*self.margin
        self.ybounds = [yrest.min()-margin, yrest.max()+margin]
        self.timer = self.ax.figure.canvas.new_timer(interval=10)
        self.timer.single_shot = True
        self.timer.add_callback(self.change_y)
        self.timer.start()

    def change_y(self):
        self.ax.set_ylim(self.ybounds)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


x=np.linspace(0,100,1001)
y = np.sin(x/16) + np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1001))/30.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x,y)
r = AutoScaleY(line)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That is great. Just tried it and it works. Thanks a lot. Indeed this must be the overwriting of ylim that prevented me from getting anything working. Using a timer is a nice trick. I will test if this trick is still necessary when constraining pan/zoom to x axis by holding x when panning/zooming with mouse.

Comment: OK, I confirm that when constraining the pan/zoom to x axis the timer is not necessary, which makes sense as there is no longer any auto change of ylim I suppose.